# Why is PDBParser not able to read all fpocket output files?

Tags: python, biopython

I'm using fpocket to find pockets in my PDB protein structures. The output is a ordered list of pockets `pocket0_atm.pdb`, `pocket1_atm.pdb`, etc. Some files are read into `Bio.PDB.PDBParser` without incident. Others fail with an "AssertionError".

Attempts to compare the .pdb files that work to those that fail have not shown me a consistent difference. Any ideas?

Here's the relevant section of code that's giving me trouble:

```
def get_pdb_limits(pdb_file):
    ''' Return the X,Y,Z size limits of a PDB file. '''
    p = PDB.PDBParser()
    structure = p.get_structure('test', pdb_file)
```

Comment: What's the assertion error? Can you show us some code, and possibly a stack trace?

Comment: This is the offending section:

Comment: `def get_pdb_limits(pdb_file):
    '''
    Return the X,Y,Z size limits of a PDB file.
    '''
    p = PDB.PDBParser()
    x_min, x_max = None, None
    y_min, y_max = None, None
    z_min, z_max = None, None
    structure = p.get_structure('test', pdb_file)`

but we have a work-around that looks at the ATOM lines in the fpocket output.

Comment: Thank you, AntC. In the future, just edit your post! I've done it for you, but that's where you should add such information. In this case, the stacktrace is the most important part. If my answer doesn't solve your problem, please post the specific error you get.

Answer (score 2):

According to [fpocket documentation](http://fpocket.sourceforge.net/manual_fpocket2.pdf) the pocketx_atm.pdb file only contains the atoms that are in contact with the spheres used to extract the pocket. In other words the pocket files doesn't contain complete residues which could be a source of problems in parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace, it's impossible to actually know what your problem is. However, `PDB.PDBParser` is built to tolerate and compensate for some errors in PDB files. Try setting `PERMISSIVE` to True, like below, and see if you still get errors.

```
p = PDB.PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
p.get_structure("pdb_id", pdb_file)
```